# What is the sum of the series $\sum_{r = 1}^{n-1}{1 \over r \sqrt[a]{\log \big(\frac{\log n}{\log r}\big)}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gamma-function

We have Euler's well known result

$$
\sum_{r = 1}^n\frac{1}{r} = \log n + \gamma + O\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)
$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-mascheroni constant. I experimentally observed a generalisation of the above. We have for $a > 1$,

$$
\sum_{r = 1}^{n-1}{1 \over r \sqrt[a]{\log \big(\frac{\log n}{\log r}\big)}} =   \Gamma\Big(1 - \frac{1}{a}\Big)\log n + C_a + O\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)
$$

where $C_a$ is a constant that depends only on $a$. If this is true than Euler's result will correspond to the special case $a \to \infty$.

**Question**: Can this be proved or disproved?

Comment: What is the first term of your sum in the lhs supposed to mean? ($0$?)

Comment: Yes zero because the denominator becomes infinity since $\log 1 = 0$

Comment: What "experimental observations" led you to this formula?

Comment: @AnneBauval I had written SageMath scripts to evaluate the sum for different values of $a$ and large $n$. The initial hint came from the fact that for $a=2$, the answer was close to $\sqrt{\pi}$ which I could immediately recognize and knew that I can be expressed as $\Gamma(1 - 1/2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S_n=\sum_{r = 1}^{n-1}{1 \over r \sqrt[a]{\ln \big(\frac{\ln n}{\ln r}\big)}}=\sum_{r = 1}^{n-1}e^{-\ln r} \ln^{-\frac1a} \big(\frac{\ln n}{\ln r}\big)$$
Switching to integration and using $dr=d(e^{\ln r})=e^{\ln r}d(\ln r)$
$$S_n\sim\int_1^{n-1}e^{-\ln r} \ln^{-\frac1a} \big(\frac{\ln n}{\ln r}\big)dr=\int_1^{n-1}\ln^{-\frac1a} \big(\frac{\ln n}{\ln r}\big)d(\ln r)$$
$$\overset{x=\frac{\ln r}{\ln n}}{=}\ln n\int_0^\frac{\ln (n-1)}{\ln n}(-\ln x)^{-\frac1a} \,dx\overset{x=e^{-s}}{=}\ln n\int_{\ln(\frac{\ln n}{\ln(n-1)})}^\infty e^{-s}s^{-\frac1a}ds$$
$$=\ln n\int_0^\infty e^{-s}s^{-\frac1a}ds-\ln n\int_0^\frac{\ln (n-1)}{\ln n} e^{-s}s^{-\frac1a}ds$$
$$=\ln n\,\Gamma\left(1-\frac1a\right)-\frac{\ln^\frac1a n}{(1-\frac1a)\,n^{1-\frac1a}}+O\left(\frac{\ln^\frac1a n}{n^{2-\frac1a}}\right)$$
A numeric evaluation shows that there is also a constant term (for example, for $a=2\,\,C_{a=2}\approx -\,0.1982...\,)$, though I'm not sure whether we can get it in a closed form.

The Euler–Maclaurin summation formula suggests that
$$S_n= \ln n\,\Gamma\left(1-\frac1a\right)+C_a+O\left(\frac{\ln^\frac1a n}{n^{1-\frac1a}}\right);\quad a> 1$$

Comment: You should decide whether it is $\log$ or $\ln$ that you prefer to use.

Comment: @Gary, thank you. Corrected.

Comment: Try writing down the Euler–Maclaurin formula with remainder and see if the remainder integral converges as $n\to +\infty$. In that way you get an improper integral formula for $C_a$.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I am surprised the constant $C_a$ is independent of$a$. I thought I would be dependent on $a$.

Comment: @Nilotpal Sinha My apology. I evaluated $C_a$ numerically for $a=2$. Just editing